# A formal/informal way to say I don't want anything

Tags: word-choice, expressions, set-phrases, culture

I was told that is ok to use

> 何でもないが欲しいです。

in an informal setting for "I don't want anything."

Is this correct? And what is an expression I can use in a formal situation?

Answer (score 11):

If the scenario were saying "I don't want anything" in response to someone offering you something (food, drink, etc.), you could also use

> （私は）[結構]{けっ・こう}です。　→　I'm fine/all right.

Comment: If you are looking for the most common phrase in these situations, I would have to say that this was the MOST common of all phrases I heard while I was in Japan, like, maybe twice as much as all others combined! Usually preceded by いや or something similar.

Answer (score 6):

何でもないが欲しいです would mean 'It's nothing, but I want it.' Honestly it makes very little sense. You seem to have taken 何でもない as a noun, but really it's a full phrase meaning 'It's nothing.' To say you don't want anything, I think 何も欲しくない would work (though I'm probably wrong). It would be a little more natural to say 何も要らない 'I don't need anything', though, I think. Formally you could say 何も要らないです or 何も要りません.

Comment: I think 何*で*もしくない would be better for saying "I don't want anything". However, as in English, there's a difference between 欲しくない and 要らない: the same as between "I don't want" and I don't "need". 何でもしくない sound more like "I no longer have desire for anything", while 何も要らない just sounds like "I'm okay".

Comment: i was thinking i'd phrase it as ほしいものはない. i'd be interested on feedback on this.

Comment: @A.Ellett I think it's more neutral than 何でもしくない, since 何でも sounds quite impulsive. IMO however, it would be more used as a question ( ほしいものは? -ない), or in an indirect speech (ほしいものはないと言ってる), but it feels too generic to be used for taking about oneself. This is however just how it feels to me, maybe someone could confirm.

Comment: @Rightleg 「何でもしくない」って？何かのタイポですよね？

Comment: あ、速くコーピして、間違っちゃったでしう。「何でも欲しくない」ですよ~

Comment: "I don't need/want anything"の意味で「何でも欲しくない」とは言いませんね・・「何も欲しくない」とか「何も要らない」でいいと思います

Comment: しかし、「何でも欲しくないよ」と言うと、「聞くのをやめて」とかと言う意味だと感じています... そうしても正しくないでしょうか。

Comment: う～ん・・「何でも欲しくない」って言われたら、ちょっと意味がわかんないと思います。。「何であろうと、欲しくない」(I wouldn't want it whatever it might be) とか「何でもかんでも欲しいわけではない」(It's not that I want anything/everything) とかいう意味だと思うかなぁ・・

Answer (score 0):

In formal way: 申{もう}し訳{わけ}ありませんが何{なに}も欲{ほ}しくありません。 / 申{もう}し訳{わけ}ありませんが何{なに}も要{い}りません。

In informal way: 何{なに}も欲{ほ}しくない（よ）。 / 何{なに}も欲{ほ}しくないんだ。 / 何{なに}も要{い}らない（よ）。

**Postscript**
何も要らない is better than 何も欲しくない, which is written in **Nothing at all**'s answer.